# PHP correct if statement?

Tags: php

I write a lot of if statements like this to check for an empty variable especially from mysql but is there an better/alternative syntax?

```
if($a!=""){
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use [`empty()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function

```
if(!empty($a)) {
```

Answer (score 3):

The fastest:

```
if ($a) { /* ... */ }
```

The funniest:

```
if (isset($a[0])) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: what if ($a = 0)? OP need to check if the value is empty. Zero is not empty. The second one is better.

Comment: True. It depends what kind of values are possible in that variable.

Comment: empty produces the same results on "0"

Answer (score 1):

Well syntax it is correct.

But `" "` is not empty so you could look at `trim()` for that.

I prefer the function `strlen` in combination with `trim`

```
if (strlen(trim($a))
```

If you prefer to be faster you could make your own function

```
function is_empty($string) {
  return (strlen(trim($string)) === 0);
}
```

Comment: as said " " is not an empty string, so empty will return false. Will the space is also empty (in most cases)

Comment: OH.. I see what you mean (blonde moment) I kept thinking yea a space isn't empty why are you rewriting the empty function!! I see what you mean now, good suggestion.

Comment: Checking the zero index is much more faster then strlen().

Answer (score 0):

If you are just doing a one liner then you can use logical short circuting

```
$a && print ("Goodbye"); // same as $a != ""
```

or

```
$a || print ("Hello World"); // same as $a == ""
```

This leverages how PHP (and most languages) optimize binary operators

For the first case if $a results in a truthy value then the interpreter knows that it has to check the right hand side of the equation to determine the result of the expression.

If it is a falsey value then it wont evaluate the right hand side because it know's that it doesn't matter.

Similar logic is applied to the || statement

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
!empty($a) ? (/* if not empty */) : (/* else */);
```